# Convert month column into row and aggregate other columns under it

Tags: python, pandas, logic, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have data like this

```
user    product     month
 A       1011         2
 B       2011         2
 B       2034         3
 C       2078         4
 D       1098         1
 A       9087         3
 A       5017         4
 D       1872         1
 A       1011         4
```

and so on

I want to aggregate this data such that, convert month column into row, as in they become the headers, and I can aggregate 'product' with unique values under each user and in which month they were accessed. So output should be something like this

```
user   product  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
 A       3      0  1  1  2  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
 B       2      0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
 C       1      0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
 D       2      2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```

I think I can use Pivot to get this done but I am not able to aggregate under the month header.

I want to go a step ahead, and divide the product with each month to find utilization rate each month, for example:

```
user   product  1   2     3     4     5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
 A       3      0  0.33  0.33   0.66  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
 B       2      0  0.50  0.50    0    0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
 C       1      0   0     0      1    0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
 D       2      1   0     0      0    0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `nunqiue` get the first two columns, then we using `get_dummies` get the others

```
s1=df.groupby('user').product.nunique()
s2=df.set_index('user').month.astype(str).str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
pd.concat([s1,s2.div(s1,axis=0)],1)
Out[121]: 
      product    1         2         3         4
user                                            
A           3  0.0  0.333333  0.333333  0.666667
B           2  0.0  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
C           1  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
D           2  1.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Well sir, you are awesome! :)